# Start any embedded video (iframe) at certain time code?

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, time

Is there a way to start any embedded video at a certain time code position? I know from YouTube and Vimeo you can append a #t=TIMECODE to the URL but it obviously doesn't work for any player, is there a universal solution for example using javascript?